# users class in google apps engine 1.8

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

After upgrading to latest python gae-1.8, I got the following error on [appspot.com](http://appspot.com):

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'email'`

The same code working fine from dev server.

The actual code is:

`entity.username = users.GetCurrentUser().email()`

I tried the original `get_current_user()` function but got the same.

The application is not public. it has been configured to work only from specific Apps domain. Also it was working fine on 1.7.5 version.

And I use one account only to avoid multiple accounts issues.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

The docs for get_current_user() says

> get_current_user() Returns the User object for the current user (the
>   user who made the request being processed) if the user is signed in,
>   or None if the user is not signed in

Given your error is `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'email'` then the user is not logged in and the call is returning None.

I am using auth with a specific app domain, and everything is working fine.  So I don't believe it is a general runtime (1.8.0) issue.

Comment: Thank you Tim for your fast response. returning None is not possible as the application is opening to only specific domain apps users, therefore, they should login before using it.

Comment: Be careful about saying not possible ;-)  You are getting None back so clearly it is possible.  How are you preventing a request to a URL that is protected?  And how are you protecting/ guarding a URL, to ensure the user is logged in?

Comment: Thank you. yes it returns None :). I'm protecting the login by selecting Google Apps domain from the Authentication Type in Application settings. then adding the application to Google Apps services same as Google Market. this way limit the application to be available only to specific GA domain and therefore, no need to check valid users as  they must login to that domain before accessing the application.

Comment: Umm, I don't believe anything is specifically preventing the user from accessing the URL without logging in first (unless you have `login: required` in app.yaml.  Try using incognito mode in chrome and visit the URL of the app without logging in.  You should probably be checking the state of get_current_user() if it returns None, then redirect the browser to the result of create_login_url() with dest_url set to the url just attempted.

Comment: I added the following code to check for any error:
`if not users.GetCurrentUser():
            users.CreateLoginURL('/')`

it returns nothing although users logged in. 
then replaced the createLoginURL() with `self.response.write('error')`. it returned "error".

Comment: I don't know what lib you are using. But the users service  create_login_url() just returns a URL, you then need to explicitly call a redirect using that URL. And as I mentioned specify the dest_url so that after successful login the user is redirected back to the page they originally attempted.

Comment: Out of curiosity what is the users module you are using, with all the user services methods renamed with CamelCase.

Comment: When i removed the application from Apps domain it raised error. no login. added back again. nothing appear. :-/

Comment: I'm using users normal modules. the function `CreateLoginURL` is just an alias to `create_login_url`. this is new in 1.8.
I also tried normal `create_login_url`. the same issue occur.
the same code was working perfect in 1.7.5 with the same restrictions.

Comment: I added `login: required` to app.yaml file. it's now working fine.

To conclude: when Authentication Type: Google Apps Engine. and when specifying domain, we require login at app.yaml even if users currently logged in already.

Please advise if this is a good logic in user service ot not.

Thank you Tim for your effort and sorry for bothering you :).

Comment: You do need login required if logging in is not optional. My guess is you never really tested with users not logged in.

Comment: sure I tested. but not tested with no `login: required` line in app.yaml.